# Regex to match a string after colon ":"

Tags: regex

I need to identify a sub string from any string based on a regular expression.

For Example, take the following strings:

1. It sent a notice of delivery of goods: UserName1
2. Sent a notice of delivery of the goods: User is not found, UserName2
3. It sent a notice of receipt of the goods: UserName1
4. It sent a notice of receipt of the goods: User is not found, UserName2

I want to get the text after colon

1. UserName1
2. User is not found, UserName2
3. UserName1
4. User is not found, UserName2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the regex like this:

```
":(.*)"
```

Then, you should use something like this one (on Java):

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(":(.*)").matcher(text);

if (m.find())
{
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Comment: is there a way to do this so it excludes the colon? so for something:value, i would want it to return "value"

Comment: @Dan Hastings, did you try the code I've posted? It doesn't include a colon.

Comment: For me it returns the string with a colon at the start

Comment: @DanHastings But it can't. My example on Java works perfectly, so I can't tell you what you're doing wrong. You may ask a new question and provide the code that returns a string with a colon.

Comment: ":(.*)" is returning the colon on https://regexr.com/ when i add the string "style: block"

Answer (score 6):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
(?<=:).*
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher; import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MatchColon {

    private Pattern pattern;
    private Matcher matcher;

    private static final String MATCHCOLON_PATTERN =
        ":(.*)";

    public MATCHCOLON(){
      pattern = Pattern.compile(MATCHCOLON_PATTERN);
    }

    public boolean validate(final String colon){
      matcher = pattern.matcher(colon);
      return matcher.matches();
    }
}
```